# plot an interferogram as a function of time in matlab

Tags: matlab, fft

Can someone help me to understand how to plot an interferogram as a function of time in matlab?
my data are looking like that:

```
Points  Interferogram
0   -2.11E-04
1   -1.16E-04
2   -5.71E-05
3   -7.64E-05
4   -1.58E-04
...
```

up to about 28000.

I need to put it in this form to do a fast fourier transform to extract the spectrum with this code (that isn't complete):

```
clear all
format long 

readpath='C:\Users\lady-\Desktop\CS2\'; 
filename1  = 'Interferogram1.txt'; 
    [pos1, I1] = textread([readpath, filename1], '%f %f', 'headerlines',1);

%filename2  = 'Interferogram2.txt'; 
    %[pos2, I2] = textread([readpath, filename2], '%f %f', 'headerlines',1);

%The full stage displacement is 9.166 mm 


% figure(1)
plot(pos1,I1)
% title('Interferogram')Assuming that the x component has units of time (s):
%timestep = mean(diff(t));           % Timestep (s)
%Fs = 1./timestep;                   % Sampling frequency in [Hz]    
%n_FFT = length(t);
%Ef_1 = fft(I1,n_FFT); 
%Ef_2 = fft(I2,n_FFT); 

%Keeping only the positive frequencies
%NumUniquePts = ceil((n_FFT+1)/2); 
%Ef1 = Ef_1(1:NumUniquePts);
%Ef2 = Ef_2(1:NumUniquePts);
```

Thank you !

Comment: Besides not knowing how you derive your variable `t` (time) your code looks okay. So what exactly is your problem / question?

Comment: I don't understand how to get the time from the data, with the stage displacement and the ZPD I know that I can have the intensity as a function of the moving mirror but how can you have the time out of it?

Comment: looking at the few lines of data, it seems that there is no information stored in your file. So you need to inform yourself what is the sampling  time of your device which stores the data.

Comment: I presume you are measuring a linear auto-correlation of a wave of light (one copy times another, delayed , copy) as in a Michelson. The Fourier transform of that is the intensity spectrum.  No need for time. Each datapoint has a position. The delta between two of them is the position resolution. The inverse of this resolution gives you the range of wavelengths. The inverse of the range of positions (last vs first) gives you the resolution of the spectrum. There is also a factor 2 involved (each step with your piezo shortened the path of the light by 2x). For time, divide by speed of light.